# Recommendations for a scoring formula for sorting a location based social network's post feed

Tags: calculus, polynomials, algorithms, graphing-functions, cauchy-integral-formula

I'm building a location based social networking app. The idea is to allow users to post and interact with people nearby. The main feed of the app would show posts based on their proximity (d = how far the post was posted) and recency (a = how long ago was it posted).

I am trying to come up with a formula which would score each post for sorting and achieve the following objectives:

- High recency and high proximity posts show first (e.g d=1km, a=1 hour)
- If a post is high proximity but quite old (e.g. d=1km, a=5 days), slightly further results (e.g. d=5km, a=1 hour) rank higher
- Very far off posts (e.g. d=10000, a=1 hour) would only rank higher than nearby posts which are extremely old (e.g. d=10km, a=1 year)

**We are trying to strike a balance between seeing things which are local enough too be relevant yet fresh.** While algorithmic solutions are possible, at this point we are looking for a formula to score and sort posts. Looking for suggestions for suitable scoring formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using a bounded radius instead of letting all posts show no matter how far away?

As for a recommendation I would suggest posttimeinmilliseconds/sqrt(distance)

Comment: Hi Matt. Had thought of that but if there is no activity in your proximity would rather show you results from slightly further off that show you nothing. Also if the only post in your vicinity is a year old (which you've probably seen multiple times) would rather show you new posts from slightly further away.

Comment: Will try it out. Shouldnt the time (how long ago it was posted) be in the denominator since the lower it, the higher the score should be?

Comment: Not if your storing it as the time in ms, if you take the difference in current time to the time it was stored yes, but using just the post time will get you more relevant results